# Grouped scatter plot with interpolation in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I tend to use other tools for data visualisation but have been asked to use Excel for a given plot. That is, I need to plot one column against another and separate the data into different lines by the contents of a third. This is easy as pie in most software solutions I am used to but I can't seem to find a solution for Excel.

My data is rather simple, I will give a mockup below (My real data set is, of course, much larger):
`Category   x    y 
 A          1    10
 A          5    35
 A          10   50 
 B          1    7
 B          5    31
 B          10   40`

I need to plot categories A and B as two different lines within the same axis. For example as a red and blue points with appropriately coloured interpolation lines as well. The x-column should denote the x values and the y-column should be the y values.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any straightforward solution in Excel, my best workaround:

1. create a pivot table to organize your data in columns by category
2. copy and paste pivot table data into a new location (you can't insert scatter plot on pivot table)
3. insert scatter plot

[image]

Instead of pivot table and copy-paste, you can also set up a range where you get the desired layout with some complex formulas, but that also requires control when you change data, and for large datasets it'll take time to recalculate.

Comment: Not straightforward is right. That is rather clunky! What about interpolation lines? Error bars or confidence regions for the interpolation lines?

Comment: What are "interpolation lines"? You can add trendlines the same way as they are used in any other excel charts. Unfortunately Excel doesn't support error bars for trendlines.

Comment: Interpolation is the use of data points to formulate an equation which fits the data. It is commonly referred to as fitting. In this case I would use a linear model, e.g. f(x)=a+bx. Some visualisation software allows you to include the uncertainty in this fit as well as the fit itself in a plot.

Comment: you can use a linear trendline for that. As I've already written, there is no further functionality for that in Excel.

Comment: @Mr.V You can use `LINEST()` to get the slope and intercept. Or `SLOPE()` and `INTERCEPT()`, they do the same thing.